# Statsmodels throws "overflow in exp" and "divide by zero in log" warnings and pseudo-R squared is -inf

Tags: python, statistics, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I want to do a Logistic Regression in Python using Statsmodels.

X and y have 750 rows each, y is the the binary outcome and in X are the 10 features (including the intecept).

Here are the first 12 rows of X (last column is the intercept):

```
      lngdp_      lnpop    sxp      sxp2    gy1    frac  etdo4590  geogia  \
0   7.367709  16.293980  0.190  0.036100 -1.682   132.0         1   0.916   
1   7.509883  16.436258  0.193  0.037249  2.843   132.0         1   0.916   
2   7.759187  16.589224  0.269  0.072361  4.986   132.0         1   0.916   
3   7.922261  16.742384  0.368  0.135424  3.261   132.0         1   0.916   
4   8.002359  16.901037  0.170  0.028900  1.602   132.0         1   0.916   
5   7.929126  17.034786  0.179  0.032041 -1.465   132.0         1   0.916   
6   6.594413  15.627563  0.360  0.129600 -9.321  4134.0         0   0.648   
7   6.448889  16.037861  0.476  0.226576 -2.356  3822.0         0   0.648   
8   8.520786  16.919334  0.048  0.002304  2.349   434.0         1   0.858   
9   8.637107  16.991980  0.050  0.002500  2.326   434.0         1   0.858   
10  8.708144  17.075489  0.042  0.001764  1.421   465.0         1   0.858   
11  8.780480  17.151779  0.080  0.006400  1.447   496.0         1   0.858   

    peace  intercept  
0    24.0        1.0  
1    84.0        1.0  
2   144.0        1.0  
3   204.0        1.0  
4   264.0        1.0  
5   324.0        1.0  
6     1.0        1.0  
7    16.0        1.0  
8   112.0        1.0  
9   172.0        1.0  
10  232.0        1.0  
11  292.0        1.0
```

This is my code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

logit = sm.Logit(y, X, missing='drop')
result = logit.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

This is the output:

> ```
>      Optimization terminated successfully.
>
>      Current function value: inf
>
>      Iterations 9
> ```
>
> /home/ipattern/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:1214:
>   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
>   return 1/(1+np.exp(-X))
>
> /home/ipattern/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:1264:
>   RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
>   return
>   np.sum(np.log(self.cdf(q*np.dot(X,params))))

```
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  warsa   No. Observations:                  750
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                      740
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            9
Date:                Tue, 12 Sep 2017   Pseudo R-squ.:                    -inf
Time:                        11:16:58   Log-Likelihood:                   -inf
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                   -4.6237e+05
                                        LLR p-value:                     1.000
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lngdp_        -0.9504      0.245     -3.872      0.000      -1.431      -0.469
lnpop          0.5105      0.128      3.975      0.000       0.259       0.762
sxp           16.7734      5.206      3.222      0.001       6.569      26.978
sxp2         -23.8004     10.040     -2.371      0.018     -43.478      -4.123
gy1           -0.0980      0.041     -2.362      0.018      -0.179      -0.017
frac          -0.0002    9.2e-05     -2.695      0.007      -0.000   -6.76e-05
etdo4590       0.4801      0.328      1.463      0.144      -0.163       1.124
geogia        -0.9919      0.909     -1.091      0.275      -2.774       0.790
peace         -0.0038      0.001     -3.808      0.000      -0.006      -0.002
intercept     -3.4375      2.486     -1.383      0.167      -8.310       1.435
==============================================================================
```

The coefficients, std err, p value etc. at the bottom are correct (I know this because I have the "solution").

But as you can see the `Current function value is inf` which is wrong I think.

And I get two warnings. Apparently statsmodels does np.exp(BIGNUMBER), e.g. np.exp(999) and np.log(0) somewhere.

Also `Pseudo R-squ. is -inf` and `Log-Likelihood is -inf`, which shouldn't be `-inf` I think.

So what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

X.describe():

```
           lngdp_       lnpop         sxp        sxp2         gy1  \
count  750.000000  750.000000  750.000000  750.000000  750.000000   
mean     7.766948   15.702191    0.155329    0.043837    1.529772   
std      1.045121    1.645154    0.140486    0.082838    3.546621   
min      5.402678   11.900227    0.002000    0.000004  -13.088000   
25%      6.882694   14.723123    0.056000    0.003136   -0.411250   
50%      7.696212   15.680984    0.111000    0.012321    1.801000   
75%      8.669355   16.652981    0.203000    0.041209    3.625750   
max      9.851826   20.908354    0.935000    0.874225   14.409000   

              frac    etdo4590      geogia       peace  intercept  
count   750.000000  750.000000  750.000000  750.000000      750.0  
mean   1812.777333    0.437333    0.600263  348.209333        1.0  
std    1982.106029    0.496388    0.209362  160.941996        0.0  
min      12.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000        1.0  
25%     176.000000    0.000000    0.489250  232.000000        1.0  
50%     864.000000    0.000000    0.608000  352.000000        1.0  
75%    3375.000000    1.000000    0.763000  472.000000        1.0  
max    6975.000000    1.000000    0.971000  592.000000        1.0
```

logit.loglikeobs(result.params):

```
array([ -4.61803704e+01,  -2.26983454e+02,  -2.66741244e+02,
        -2.60206733e+02,  -4.75585266e+02,  -1.76454554e+00,
        -4.86048292e-01,  -8.02300533e-01,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,  -6.02780923e+02,
        -4.12209348e+02,  -6.42901288e+02,  -6.94331125e+02,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf,
                   -inf,             -inf,             -inf, ...
```

(logit.exog * np.array(result.params)).min(0):

```
array([ -9.36347474,   6.07506083,   0.03354677, -20.80694575,
        -1.41162588,  -1.72895247,   0.        ,  -0.9631801 ,
        -2.23188846,  -3.4374963 ])
```

Datasets:

X: https://pastebin.com/VRNSepBg

y: https://pastebin.com/j2Udyc7m

Comment: @Phillip If the dataset is public, then you could post the case to the statsmodels issue tracker https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues . I guess Logit needs to keep the predicted probabilities away from 0 and 1 which is currently not done. However, I suspect that the loglikelihood `llf` will be dominated by whatever is chosen as clipping threshold in extreme cases like this.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in my mind, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am surprised that it still converges in this case.

There can be convergence problems with overflow with exp functions as used in Logit or Poisson when the x values are large. This can often be avoided by rescaling the regressors.

However, in this case my guess would be outliers in x. The 6th column has values like 4134.0 while the others are much smaller.

You could check the loglikelihood for each observation  `logit.loglikeobs(result.params)` to see which observations might cause problems, where `logit` is the name that references the model

Also the contribution of each predictor might help, for example

`np.argmax(np.abs(logit.exog * result.params), 0)`

or

`(logit.exog * result.params).min(0)`

If it's just one or a few observations, then dropping them might help. Rescaling the exog will most likely not help for this, because upon convergence it will just be compensated by a rescaling of the estimated coefficient.

Also check whether there is not an encoding error or a large value as place holder for missing values.

**edit**

Given that the number of `-inf` in loglikeobs seems to be large, I think that there might be a more fundamental problem than outliers, in the sense that the Logit model is not the correctly specified maximum likelihood model for this dataset.

Two possibilites in general (because I haven't seen the dataset):

Perfect separation: Logit assumes that the predicted probabilities stay away from zero and one. In some cases an explanatory variable or combination of them allows perfect prediction of the dependent variable. In this case the parameters are either not identified or go to plus or minus infinity. The actual parameter estimates depend on the convergence criteria for the optimization. Statsmodels Logit detects some cases for this and then raises and PerfectSeparation exception, but it doesn't detect all cases with partial separation.

Logit or GLM-Binomial are in the one parameter linear exponential family. The parameter estimates in this case only depend on the specified mean function and the implied variance. It does not require that the likelihood function is correctly specified. So it is possible to get good (consistent) estimates even if the likelihood function is not correct for the given dataset. In this case the solution is a quasi-maximum likelihood estimator, but the loglikelihood value is invalid.

This can have the effect that the results in terms of convergence and numerical stability depend on the computational details for how the edge or extreme cases are handled. Statsmodels is clipping the values to keep them away from the bounds in some cases but not yet everywhere.

The difficulty is in figuring out what to do about numerical problems and to avoid returning "some" numbers without warning the user when the underlying model is inappropriate for or incompatible with the data.

Maybe `llf = -inf` is the "correct" answer in this case, and any finite numbers are just approximation for -inf. Maybe it's just a numerical problem because of the way the functions are implemented in double precision.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I edited my post and added the things you said.

In R with the glm()-function everything looks normal. There are no warnings etc. and pseudo R squared is not -inf for example.

Comment: You could also try statmodels GLM Binomial which is the same model as Logit for binary endog but uses a different numerical approach. In non-edge and non-extreme cases the two models produce identical results. GLM has also deviance (which might however run into the same overflow problems).

Comment: I added the datasets at the bottom of my question (if you want to try it out).

I tried statsmodels GLM Binomial and it works fine! 

As you said, it is difficult to find what is wrong with statsmodels's Logit function, so I think am going with the GLM Binomial function.

Also, what do you mean with `llf = -inf` is the correct answer?